# IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM Not Escaping $ in username

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I am trying to use this Microsoft task [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp&ssr=false#overview) to create a new website in iis. One of the configuration parameters is a username with the right privilages to make changes in the target machine. This is fine, but the username i am provided to do this happens to have a $ as part of the name. Let's sayy the username value looks something like this MyDomain\AAA$BBB$CCC ,this completely messes up the execution, probably because $ is not being escaped correctly. If I use a login which does not have the $ everything works as expected. I have tried all sort of ways to escape the dollar before assigning with no luck. Any ideas how to get around this?

Logs:

```
> 2020-09-23T13:34:06.2439758Z ##[section]Starting: Manage IISWebsite
2020-09-23T13:34:06.2452475Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-23T13:34:06.2452600Z Task         : WinRM - IIS Web App Management
2020-09-23T13:34:06.2452664Z Description  : Connect via WinRM, to create or update a Website, Web App, Virtual Directories, and Application Pool locally on IIS
2020-09-23T13:34:06.2452725Z Version      : 3.0.0
2020-09-23T13:34:06.2452763Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-09-23T13:34:06.2452805Z Help         : [More Information](http://aka.ms/IISMgmt)
2020-09-23T13:34:06.2452858Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-23T13:34:09.4989327Z Starting remote execution of Invoke-Main script for "IISWebsite" with action "CreateOrUpdateWebsite"
2020-09-23T13:34:10.7101893Z PSSession created for Machines:'BBBAPP05'
2020-09-23T13:34:12.5340174Z ================================================ BBBAPP05 ================================================
2020-09-23T13:34:12.5942534Z ##[command]& 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\Users\AAA$BBB$CCC\AppData\Local\Temp\eef005c2-911f-48e6-9a83-7ee59496b299.ps1'"
2020-09-23T13:34:42.6124922Z ================================================ BBBAPP05 ================================================
2020-09-23T13:34:42.7415929Z . : The term 'C:\Users\AAA\AppData\Local\Temp\eef005c2-911f-48e6-9a83-7ee59496b299.ps1' is not recognized as the name 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.7417078Z At line:1 char:1
2020-09-23T13:34:42.7417328Z + & 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -NoLogo -NoProfile ...
2020-09-23T13:34:42.7417499Z + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-09-23T13:34:42.7417571Z     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (. : The term 'C...ed as the name :String) [], RemoteException
2020-09-23T13:34:42.7419615Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
2020-09-23T13:34:42.7420351Z  
2020-09-23T13:34:42.7421348Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.7855083Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.7943983Z of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.7944127Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.7946475Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.8236229Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.8299665Z verify that the path is correct and try again.
2020-09-23T13:34:42.8299832Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.8303916Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.8409026Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.8478481Z At line:1 char:3
2020-09-23T13:34:42.8479137Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.8479391Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.8580860Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.8645911Z + . 'C:\Users\AAA\AppData\Local\Temp\eef005c2-911f-48e6-9a83-7ee59496b299.ps1'
2020-09-23T13:34:42.8646010Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.8647804Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.8762679Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.8827401Z +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-09-23T13:34:42.8828235Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.8830818Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.8938514Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.9003212Z     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\AAA\Ap...ee59496b299.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
2020-09-23T13:34:42.9003413Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.9005450Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.9112517Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.9174709Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
2020-09-23T13:34:42.9174967Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.9177224Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.9280850Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.9342560Z  
2020-09-23T13:34:42.9343493Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.9345033Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:42.9451075Z 
2020-09-23T13:34:44.1700359Z ##[error]Non-Zero exit code: '1' for ComputerName: 'BBBAPP05'
2020-09-23T13:34:44.2602724Z ##[section]Finishing: Manage IISWebsite
```

Comment: What's the real error message do you get? `Access denied` or something else?

Comment: I included the logs for the task attempting to create the iis site and app pool. Notice how the script tries to execute a temp script under the user directory C:\Users\AAA\AppData\Local\Temp\eef005c2-.......  However the user name is AAA$BBB$CCC. If I use a user without $ the correct user folder is used for the temp script and everything works.

Comment: What about surrounding the username with `' '` or `" "`, a bit difference? `Domain\Username`, "Domain\Username", Domain\`Username`...